# Call Java method from JNI

Tags: java, android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

In some C library exists function with signature: int someFunction(int a);

I need to call Java methods from this function (from native code) so as not to break the interface.
For example:

```
int someFunction(int a) {
    ...
    jbyteArray result = (jbyteArray)(*jEnv)->CallStaticObjectMethod(jEnv, clazz, methodId);
    ...
}
```

I *can't* put any extra arguments like `JNIEnv` in `someFunction` needed by `JNI` so I declare global variables and functions for initialization:

```
jmethodID globalMethodId;
jclass globalClass;
JavaVM* globalJVM;

void initJNI(JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz) {
    globalClass = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, clazz);
    (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &globalJVM);

    globalMethodId = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, clazz, "javaMethodName", "()[B");
}

JNIEnv * GetJniEnv() {
    JNIEnv * env;
    if((*globalJVM)->AttachCurrentThread(globalJVM, &env, NULL) != JNI_OK) {
        env = NULL;
    }
    return env;
}
```

and my someFunction function is as follows

```
int someFunction(int a) {
    JNIEnv * jEnv = GetJniEnv();
    jbyteArray result = (jbyteArray)(*jEnv)->CallStaticObjectMethod(jEnv, globalClass, globalMethodId);
    ...
}
```

And user of this new library must call `initJNI` function and thereafter call someFunction.

Is it not error prone way? How about multithreading? Is there more preferable solution.

Comment: I don't think you can count on those values you copy to globals remaining valid after the return of the function that was given them. In my own similar situation, also on Android, I had problems with it that were solved when I stopped storing the pointers as globals and instead updated them and time the JVM called into my module.

Comment: You should be ok to cache the vm pointer, that wont change, but you will need to get the `JNIEnv` to ensure multithread compatibility, like you have above.

Comment: If I'm dealing with one-thread application can I make one-time initialization of JNIEnv global and then use it with multiple call of jni method (in one thread).

Answer (score -1):

I know this is old , but peoples still find it from searches .

Here is full solution , how to call C code from java ,and call back java code from jni c code:

Create Android.mk in your project jni dir

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=false
LOCAL_MODULE := testjni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := testjni.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -ljnigraphics
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Create Application.mk in your project jni dir

```
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Create testjni.c in your project jni dir

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include <android/log.h>

#define LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"TAG",__VA_ARGS__)

JavaVM *myVm;

static void *android_gui = NULL;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
{
    // Keep a reference on the Java VM.
    myVm = vm;

    LOGD("JNI interface loaded.");

    return JNI_VERSION_1_2;
}


void jni_setDataEnv(JNIEnv *p_env, int width, int height)
{
    if (android_gui == NULL)
        return;

    jclass cls = (*p_env)->GetObjectClass (p_env, android_gui);

    jmethodID methodId = (*p_env)->GetMethodID (p_env, cls, "setData", "(II)V");

    //add or delete II's depinding your number or variable passsed

    (*p_env)->CallVoidMethod (p_env, android_gui, methodId, width, height);

    (*p_env)->DeleteLocalRef(p_env, cls);
}

void jni_setData(int width, int height)
{

    JNIEnv *p_env;

    (*myVm)->AttachCurrentThread (myVm, &p_env, NULL);

    jni_setDataEnv(p_env, width, height);

    int check = (*myVm)->GetEnv(myVm, (void *) &p_env, JNI_VERSION_1_2);

    LOGD(" Detach destructor = %d", check);

    if (check != JNI_EDETACHED)
     {

        int detach = (*myVm)->DetachCurrentThread (myVm);

        LOGD("Detach result ==: %d", detach);

     }


}

//change this to your package

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_test_LibTest_initM(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jobject gui)
{

   android_gui = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, gui);

}


//when you need , in your c code call jni_setData(100.200 ) and
//MainActivity method , setData() will receive this values

void *call_from_thread()
{
    jni_setData(1,2);
    return NULL;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_test_LibTest_test(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz)
{


    pthread_t t;
    //do hard work in a thread
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, call_from_thread, NULL);


}
```

in jni folder run ndk-build to compile the library libtest.so

Create : MyInterface.java in your java android project src

```
package com.example.test;

public interface MyInterface
{

    void setData(int width, int height);

}
```

Create LibTest.java  //used to send data to C code from java

```
package com.example.test;

public class LibTest 
{

  static 
  {
     System.loadLibrary("testjni");
  }

  private static LibTest sInstance;

  public static LibTest getInstance() 
   {
        synchronized (LibTest.class) 
          {
            if (sInstance == null) 
              {
                /* First call */
                sInstance = new LibTest();
              }
           }

        return sInstance;
   }

   public native void initM( MyInterface myinterface );

   public native void test();

}
```

Create  MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface 
{
    int mHeight;
    int mWidth;

    LibTest libtest;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        libtest = LibTest.getInstance();

        libtest.initM( MainActivity.this );


        //tell jni to send us some data
        //we receive data in 'setData(int width, int height)' method

        libtest.test();

    }

@Override
public void setData(int width, int height) 
{
    /// Here you receive data from C code 
    //We can store the values C send to Java so we use latter

    mHeight = height;
    mWidth  = width;

    Log.d("TAG" ,"GOT SOME DATA FROM C CODE" + mHeight + " " + mWidth );


}

}
```